# Why can´t I place a texture in the colour bar anymore?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

So I am watching the "Blender Beginners UV Unwrapping Tutorial", but cannot see how to add a texture to my material like in the color bar in the video
(there should be a dot to click on). I remember having done this before. Has the current version of blender changed so much or am I missing something?

This is what it should look like
[image]

and how it looks at my screen, i see no option for adding an imagetexture
[image]

Comment: please add the tutorial link and approximate minute for what you're referring to... (or, better, an image from it, embedded here)

Comment: No one else but you knows what tutorial you are doing, and what you have on your screen, or what dot you refer to. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong render engine. You want to be using cycles, but you are using Blender Render. At the top of the screen there is an option to change the engine. You can see in the first screenshot where it says Cycles Render.

Comment: haven´t thought about that, of course!